# Joomla menu manager options are not displaying

Tags: css, caching, joomla, menu, title

I have built a menu item where I am trying to apply a custom CSS class in the “Page Display Options.”

I have the settings configured as you can see below:

[image]

When I refresh the page, I am getting no title pulling through or the customized `hide_password_field` class.

I have tried a handful of things that I would think to do with no luck.  Examples are clearing cache and emptying browser.

Comment: Have you ensured you running the latest version of Joomla 2.5? Sill question but are you by any chance for example making these changes on your localhost and trying to view them online? I only ask this as I have made this mistake before

Comment: @Lodder I have verified that the localhost is not the issue.  I am running Joomla 2.5.18 (icon says up to date)

Comment: What is the menu type? Article? Custom Component?

Comment: @DavidFritsch Edit Profile for Community Builder

Comment: The only custom feature of this build that may be overriding this would be the theme.  Is there a way to check this?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because there isn't a style signed to the position for that module.  In your templates JDOC element for the module position in question, make sure you have the style attribute set to XHTML.

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="my-position-name" style="xhtml" />
```